# CDF of a random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Consider a random variable $Y_{n}$ such that,

$P$($Y_{n}$ = $\frac{i}{n}$) = $\frac{1}{n}$ , $i$ = 1, 2,..., $n$.

Is the cdf of $Y_n$ for every integer $n \ge 1$ simply $\sum_{k=1}^i \frac{1}{n}$ = $\frac{i}{n}$?

Also, how do you show that for any $u$ $\in$ $R$  the $\lim_{n\to\infty} P($$Y_{n}$ $\le$ $u$) = P(U $\le$ $u$)

Where U is uniform $[0,1]$.

My thought was that if $P($$Y_{n}$ $\le$ $\frac{i}{n}$) = $\frac{i}{n}$, then $P($$Y_{n}$ $\le$ $u$) = $u$ which is equal to 
$\int_0^u$ 1 dU.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The cdf of $Y_n$ is given by
$$
P(Y_n\le y)=\frac{\lfloor ny\rfloor}n
$$
for $0\le y\le 1$, where $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ is the [floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions). We have that $\lfloor ny\rfloor/ny\to1$ as $n\to\infty$. Hence, $P(Y_n\le y)\to y$ as $n\to\infty$ which is the cdf of the continuous uniform distribution on $[0,1]$.

Alternatively, we can use the moment generating functions. The moment generating function of $Y_n$ is given by
$$
\frac{e^{t/n}[e^t-1]}{n(e^{t/n}-1)}.
$$
for $t\ne0$. We have that $e^{t/n}\to1$ as $n\to\infty$ and $n(e^{t/n}-1)\to t$ as $n\to\infty$. We obtain
$$
\frac{e^{t/n}[e^t-1]}{n(e^{t/n}-1)}\to\frac{e^t-1}t
$$
as $n\to\infty$ which is the moment generating function of the continuous uniform distribution on $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

First, it's necessary to be a bit more careful with the notation. When you say "Is the CDF of $Y_n$ for every integer $n \ge 1$... this is confusing since $n$ indexes a *sequence* of random variables $Y_n$, and thus should be avoided being used to also denote other arbitrary integers.

To reframe this problem in a clearer context, here we have a *sequence* of random variables $Y_n$. For each $n$, the probability density changes, and we have $P(Y_n = \frac{i}{n}) = \frac{1}{n}$. So, for each $n$, $Y_n$ is a discrete random variable with uniform probability mass distributed over the finite sample space $\{1, \dots, n\}.$

You are on the right track with the CDF of $Y_n$, for each $n$. The CDF, call it $G_n$ for each $n$, is $$G_n(x) := P(Y_n \le u) = \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor u \cdot n\rfloor} \frac{1}{n} $$

where $\lfloor u n \rfloor$ is the floor of $u n $, i.e. we round $u n$ down to the nearest integer.

Now we want to consider if this sequence of CDFs, $G_n$, converges to the CDF of a uniform $[0,1]$ random variable. We will denote the CDF of a standard uniform random variable as $F$. As you mentioned, $F(x) := \int^x_0 1 dt.$ By the limit definition of a definite integral, we have

\begin{align}
F(x) &= \int^x_0 1 dt \\\ &= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum^n_{i=1} 1 \cdot \Delta x_i \\\
&= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum^n_{i=1} 1 \cdot \frac {1}{n} \\\
&= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor u \cdot n \rfloor} \frac{1}{n}
\end{align}

where $\Delta x_i$ is the difference between points in any partition $x_0 = 0 < x_1 < \dots < x_{n-1} < x_n = 1$ of $[0,1]$. Clearly $x_0 = 0 < x_1 = \frac {1}{n} < \dots < x_{n-1} = \frac {n-1}{n} < x_n = \frac{n}{n}$ is such a partition, with difference $\Delta x_i = \frac {1}{n}$. Therefore we have desired CDF convergence.

Comment: You suddenly included the floor function of $u$ on top of the last series next to $n$, can you clarify why you were able to do that. Thank you.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I have a typo -- it should be $\lfloor u \cdot n \rfloor$ instead. Then, as $n \rightarrow \infty$, we also have $\lfloor u \cdot n \rfloor \rightarrow \infty.$ Fixed!

Comment: I have another general and perhaps basic math question about this. In second semester calculus we learn that $\Delta_{t}$=$\frac{b-a}{n}$, which in this case would mean $\frac{x-0}{n}$, but instead we took $\Delta_{x}$=$\frac{1-0}{n}$ with the bounds of the standard uniform $[0,1]$. I suppose it is due to presence of the dummy variable $t$ which relates back to $x$. But could you explain the logic behind this more formally, I don't think I've ever come across anything like it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Not sure what the $t$ denotes here, but to explain my notation of $\Delta x_i$, this picture might help: http://www.vias.org/calculus/img/04_integration-10.gif

Here, we are partitioning the domain of the function, the $x$-axis. We consider the "domain" in our context to be the support of a probability density function, which is the area in which the probability density function is nonzero. For a Uniform $[0,1]$ random variable, the support is $[0,1]$. We partition $[0,1]$ into tiny pieces of size $1/n$.

Answer (score 0):

The cumulative distribution function (CDF) is obtained by integration of the density:
\begin{aligned}
F_{Y_n}(t) & = \int_{-\infty}^t \sum_{i=1}^n P\!\left(Y_n=\frac{i}{n}\right) \delta_{i/n}(x) \, dx \\
& = \underset{i\leq n t}{\sum_{i=1}^n} \frac{1}{n} \\
& = \frac{1}{n} \min(n,\max (1,\lfloor n t \rfloor)) \, ,
\end{aligned}
where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta, and $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ is the floor function. When $n$ goes to infinity, this CDF tends towards the CDF of the uniform distribution over $[0,1]$:
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} F_{Y_n} (t) & = \min(1,\max (0, t )) \\
& = F_U (t) \, .
\end{aligned}